# How to do json schema validation in Eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse, schema

I'm trying to set up basic json schema validation in Eclipse.  From what I understand, Eclipse supports this, but I can't find any information about how to actually take advantage of this.

I tried putting a valid schema def (from http://json-schema.org/example1.html) in "example.schema.json" and then a syntactically valid but schema-invalid "example.json" in the same directory, and then selecting "Validate" from the context menu, but that didn't appear to do anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have JSON schema autocomplete and documentation with eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983779/is-it-possible-to-have-json-schema-autocomplete-and-documentation-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the JSON Schema to the JSON Catalog for each JSON file you want to validate. Example: To validate "faces.json" with "facesSchema.json":

Window -> Preferences -> JSON -> JSON Catalog

Add a new Entry with and enter the follwing into the dialog:

"File Match": "faces.json" and "URL": "file://../facesSchema.json"

Screenshot:
[Eclipse Settings for JSON Catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V00Or.jpg)

(I'm using Eclipse Photon)

Comment: Check, whether your schema file has a line like this:
`"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"`

Comment: You need to have Eclipse Web Developer Tools installed.