# Is it possible to have JSON schema autocomplete and documentation with eclipse?

Tags: json, eclipse, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a massive JSON setup file that I use with one of my projects. I would like to write some documentation and validation rules via a JSON schema so the edition of this file is easier for someone who's not familiar with it.

I want to be able to open the json setup file in Eclipse and have autocomplete for the json properties via intellisense. I also want to see the documentation comments for any json setup property when the mouse is over it.

I can't find any kind of documentation about this feature. Is this possible with eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, that is possible. Make sure the _Eclipse Web Developer Tools_ are installed (included in the Java EE package), add the JSON schema in _Window > Preferences: JSON > JSON Catalog_ and enable schema validation. If you find bugs or have feature requests, report them to Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger Can you direct me to any documentation for this please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any documentation about this. I tried it and the content assist proposes the properties including the descriptions from the schema file. But there is a restriction: the _File Match_ of an item of the JSON Catalog seems not to support wildcards like `*`. As alternative or workaround for this limitation, templates can be used (_Window > Preferences: JSON > JSON Files > Editor > Templates_).

Comment: I've updated the question with my research on this, thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question, cause I found the way to do it pretty easy and works quite well.

So,

> · Having a test.json file which contains the setup of your project which
>   you want to get autocomplete features on
>
> · Having a c:\test.schema.json file which contains the schema for your
>   setup file

The steps to activate this feature on eclipse are:

> 1- Open eclipse
>
> 2- go to "Window > Preferences: JSON > JSON Catalog"
>
> 3- add a new entry with "test.json" as the file and
>   "file:/c:/test.schema.json" as the URL
>
> 4- enable syntax and schema validation under "Window > Preferences:
>   JSON > JSON Files > Validation"
>
> 5- Apply the changes
>
> 6- Open the test.json file with eclipse and check that ctrl + space performs autocomplete

The only tedious part of this process that I've found is that **every time the json schema file gets modified, you have to go again to "Window > Preferences: JSON > JSON Catalog" and apply the changes again to refresh the new values**